# ToggleButton IsChecked Trigger with Storyboard Targetname Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, togglebutton

I tried to trigger a Storyboard, whichs TargetName is set to a ScrollViewer, with the ToggleButton IsChecked Property, but it says that the TargetName could not be found in the namespace of ControlTemplate.. what makes sence, but I don't know how to refer it correctly.

So I wanted following to get:

- ToggButton Click (IsChecked = true) --> ScrollViewer animates/changes trough Storyboard (StoryBoard1)
- ToggButton Click Again (IsChecked = false) --> ScrollViewer animates/changes back trough Storyboard (StoryBoard2)

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="myProject.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                  xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
                  xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Messenger4u.View"
                  mc:Ignorable="d ignore">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" SpeedRatio="3">
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" 
                          Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="200,2,0,0"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2" SpeedRatio="3">
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" 
                           Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200,2,0,0"/>
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefiniton/>
        <RowDefiniton/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Width="44" Height="34"
                  Margin="8, 0, 0, 0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsMenuOpen}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoggedIn}">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Skins/Images/btn-top-menu.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="3"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Skins/Images/btn-top-menu-hover.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard2}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the usual problem with `Controltemplate` & `XAML` structure. try below code.:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ScrollViewer x:Key="ScrollViewer"
    Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" SpeedRatio="3" >
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" 
                       Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource ScrollViewer}">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="200,2,0,0"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2" SpeedRatio="3">
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" 
                       Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource ScrollViewer}">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200,2,0,0"/>
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Width="44" Height="34"
              Margin="8, 0, 0, 0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsMenuOpen}"
              IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoggedIn}">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/SOF.gif"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="3"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/SOF.gif"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard2}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>

    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ScrollViewer}"  Grid.Row="1"/>            

</Grid>
```

> I've defined the `ScrollViewer` as a Resource and then use
>   `StoryBoard.target` property to animate. and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly give a name for the togglebutton and use it in the Storyboard.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="myToggle"
              Width="44" Height="34"
              Margin="8, 0, 0, 0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsMenuOpen}"
              IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoggedIn}">

<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" SpeedRatio="3">
    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myToggle"
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer">
        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="200,2,0,0"/>
    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Maybe I misspelled something.. I set already the TargetName to ScrollViewer, because I want to trigger the Storyboard on it and not on the ToggleButton. The ToggleButton should trigger the animation for the ScrollViewer

Comment: Sorry my bad. didnt read it properly. I am little confused though there is no scrollviewer object in the view.

Comment: No problem.. fixed it in post

Comment: Couple of things to check 0 ScrollViewer name is same as the control, so it might cause a problem. so change it to ScrollViewer1 or something. Then try applying the storyboard on the togglebutton just to see which hierarchy its able to identify. then probably we can get an idea of the problem.

Comment: With renameing the ScrollViewer to ScrollViewer1 and even setting Storyboards TargetName to the ToggleButton (myToggle) I get still the same Exception, that they cant be found in ContentControl namespace